# How to configure newsstand app in IOS 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9, newsstand-kit

Any one suggest me how to configure my app into Newsstand based.below is the screenshot 1st is the normal app and 2nd is Newsstand Based app

**1st Screenshot**
[image]
 **2nd screenshot** [image]

My question is how to set my app in newsstand based ?
and i m also proffered this [link](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/) with .plist configurations but it's not working!! and it's Old version tutorial.any one help me.thanks

Comment: AFAIK there's no newsstand app at iOS 9, it is replaced with the News app which is not available worldwide. Speaking of the Newsstand app though, I've just added a UINewsstandApp value to a project and it immediately appeared under Newsstand at iOS 8, please clarify your question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. i can't understand different with between News And Newsstand. a old version have newsstand and new version of OS have news, so can you tell me how to configure my app in Old version newsstand and New version news both are working @A-Live

Comment: I dunno, this is a completely new app and might not (and doesn't seem to) support the old behavior: instead of letting developers to put arguably related apps there they seem to use subscription feeds now https://developer.apple.com/news-publisher/